# Chrome app Unrecognized manifest key Error

Tags: google-chrome-app, manifest.json

I am getting this error once i added my chrome app to Load Unpacked.

**Unrecognized manifest key 'api_console_project_id'** and 
**Unrecognized manifest key 'container'.**

Below is the manifest.json file.

```
{
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "Welcome AppScripts",
      "version": "0.1",
      "description": "a plain text description",
      "icons": {
        "128": "favicon_128.png",
        "16": "favicon_16.png"
      },
      "container": ["DOMAIN_INSTALLABLE"],
      "api_console_project_id": "KEY",
      "app" : {
        "launch" : {
          "web_url" : "https://www.example.com"
        }
      }
    }
```

What should i need to solve this error. 
But i can able to view this app in **chrome://apps**

Comment: Simply remove those lines. The specified keys are not supported in Chrome.

Comment: Okay, then how to update those things in Chrome OS?